# Draw routes in Nutiteq 3D in Android

Tags: android, dictionary, nutiteq

Hi I am developing a Map based application where I am using Nutiteq 3D library to implement the 3D view.
But now can not draw routes between two points on that 3D map.
Can anyone please help me to draw routes between two points on that 3D map developed on Nutiteq 3D library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi,Can you share your code, how did you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nutiteq SDK itself does not have built-in function for that, but you can use external tools and services for it.

First get shortest route between two points. Here are some suggested suitable **online services** with OpenStreetMap data:

- [MapQuest Open API](http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/)

With any of them would need to create HTTP request and parse response into Line for SDK

You can also use **offline routing** tool. [GraphHopper](http://graphhopper.com/) is free routing tool under development, but quite promising already.

Then **draw the Line on map**. General instruction for adding lines, points and polygons to map can be found from [Nutiteq SDK wiki Vector Object page](https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki/Vectorobjects)

Update: there are now some routing example apps: with online and offline in [Nutiteq Wiki page](https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki/Common%20tasks#routing)